# Cloudfront file names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I am learning AWS and Cloudfront (CF) on the job in a startup. Most of the learning is not very systematic (not in depth) due to time constraints. One question I just can't find a solution for. My CF distribution is linked to an S3 bucket where all assets (CSS, JS files, etc) are. The filenames in the bucket look like this:

[image: assets in s3]

We covered CDNs at university at some point, and I remember that they calculate hashes of files and use those hashes to "find" the location (IP) of the server (in the distribution, similar to name resolution in DNS) where that file is to serve it. Maybe I misunderstood that part?

Hence the questions:

- what is that alphanumeric sequence in the names served by CF? Is that a hash?
- who calculates that value: CF, S3 or deployment process?
- why is that value different sometimes and results in 404 errors on the server?

Also, it is worth noting that at some point the deployment was done using `capistrano` (yep, it's Rails), which used `asset_sync` gem to push assets to S3. However, on the new production we are not using that - just version control on all assets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - what is that alphanumeric sequence in the names served by CF? Is that a hash?

Yep. 32-byte hash, likely SHA-256.

> - who calculates that value: CF, S3 or deployment process?

None of those. That's actually part of Rails - it adds a 'version' hash to your filenames so that you can send far-future expiration HTTP headers (for example, you can say to the client browser "cache this file, and you don't need to fetch it from the server again for a year").

Doing that without a hash creates hell when you update your assets, because every user has to hard-reload (without cache) to get the new version. If you change the version hash, and link to that in your new HTML head, then the 
browser fetches it again because it's a new file.

> - why is that value different sometimes and results in 404 errors on the server?

See above. The hash changes with every version of the asset you release; if someone tries to fetch an old asset or one with a hash that no longer exists in your S3 bucket, it'll result in a 404.

Comment: Thank you @ArtOfCode, this helps a lot.